# Command prompt shortcuts

Tags: command, cmd, command-prompt

Is it possible to create shortcuts in Windows Command Prompt? Say cd  or starting some custom application

If I type in 'abc' in the windows command prompt, the mapped command should get executed. How do I do it?

Comment: You need to give more information about what OS/shell you are interacting with for someone to help out here. Your question is very vague.

Comment: There are some good answers in [Create an alias in Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp) over at Super User.

Comment: This is not a programming question (it's an operating system question from a user's standpoint), and therefore is off-topic here. Voting to migrate to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), where it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file with `.bat` extension. Put your command with arguments in its contents. Place this file somewhere in your PATH (for example, in `C:\Windows\` folder). Now you can launch your command using basename of bat file.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make a batch file with your shortcut in it. For example, make `abc.bat` somewhere **in your path** and put something like this in it:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\SomeFolder\MyProgram.exe" %*
```

Now typing `abc` at the prompt would be the same as typing `C:\Program Files\SomeFolder\MyProgram.exe`.